# Magento 1 - How to write module google analytic "Conversions > Ecommerce Tracking"?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, google-analytics

In Magento 1.9, How to write module google analytic "Conversions > Ecommerce > Shopping Analysis " ? : include : view detail, add to cart, checkout one page ? 
If have link example or show me step by step, thanks! 
[image]

Comment: Why to write? Its available in default magento.

Comment: realy? I thinh it just tracking views ?